# Execute code whenever the space bar is pressed?

Tags: python, keyboard

I am making this kind of a game but it isn't really a game so basically I want this to run every time I hit space but it doesn't work no matter what I try so I would be really thankful if somebody could have helped me out on this.

```
import random
import keyboard

food = 5
x = 0 
y = 0 

if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
    bobsDecision = random.randint(0,1)
    if bobsDecision == 1:
        print ('bob ate')
        food = 5
    else:
        xoy = random.randint(1,4)
        if xoy == 1: 
            x = x + 1
        elif xoy == 2:
            x = x - 1
        elif xoy == 3:
            y = y + 1
        elif xoy == 4:
            y = y - 1
        food = food - 1
        print ('the cords are ', x, " ", y)
        print ('The food supply is ', food)
```

Comment: wrap your `if` statement in a `while True:` and then it should work after you start it.

Comment: @BenjaminW. be careful telling people to use `while True:` loops without also explaining the importance of some kind of exit condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `if` statement in a `while` loop. But ALSO be sure to have some kind of exit code. Below, I used the keypress `esc` to stop the while loop:

```py
import random
import keyboard

food = 5
x = 0 
y = 0 

while True:
    keyboard.read_key() # an important inclusion thanks to @wkl
    if keyboard.is_pressed('esc'):
        break
    
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
        bobsDecision = random.randint(0,1)
        if bobsDecision == 1:
            print ('bob ate')
            food = 5
        else:
            xoy = random.randint(1,4)
            if xoy == 1: 
                x = x + 1
            elif xoy == 2:
                x = x - 1
            elif xoy == 3:
                y = y + 1
            elif xoy == 4:
                y = y - 1
            food = food - 1
            print ('the cords are ', x, " ", y)
            print ('The food supply is ', food)
```

Comment: Thanks this is very useful but do you know how to make it so it only runs one time every press because when I try to press space it runs the code multiple times

Comment: This has to do with keyboard I believe. It is detecting you pressing and holding space, and, in that time, it runs the code multiple times. There has to be some logic added to only run when the key is pressed and not held

Comment: @StormGaming by default, the `keyboard` module will register as many keyboard presses as possible, so even if you press the key once, the CPU is working so fast that the period of time you're holding down the key while pressing it could be hundreds or thousands of keypresses because the loop is running that many times. A couple ways to avoid this are to use `read_key` to make it block while waiting for a keypress (like in my answer) or to register a hotkey handler.

Answer (score 2):

Your code runs once and immediately skips over `keyboard.is_pressed("space")`, and then exits.

What you want to do instead is to loop forever, and use the `keyboard` module's `read_key` functionality to make it wait for a keypress.

An example of this is this - I also added support for exiting the loop/game with `esc`.

```
import random
import keyboard

food = 5
x = 0 
y = 0 

while True:
    keyboard.read_key()
    if keyboard.is_pressed("esc"):
        print("Stopping play...")
        break
    elif keyboard.is_pressed("space"):
        bobsDecision = random.randint(0,1)
        if bobsDecision == 1:
            print ('bob ate')
            food = 5
        else:
            xoy = random.randint(1,4)
            if xoy == 1: 
                x = x + 1
            elif xoy == 2:
                x = x - 1
            elif xoy == 3:
                y = y + 1
            elif xoy == 4:
                y = y - 1
            food = food - 1
            print ('the cords are ', x, " ", y)
            print ('The food supply is ', food)
```